# GraphQL Unions and Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, sequelize.js

I'm having trouble understanding how to retrieve information from a GraphQL Union. I have something in place like this:

`const Profile = StudentProfile | TeacherProfile`

Then in my resolver I have:

```
  Profile: {
    __resolveType(obj, context, info) {
      if (obj.studentId) {
        return 'StudentProfile'
      } else if (obj.salaryGrade) {
        return 'TeacherProfile'
      }
    },
  },
```

This doesn't throw any errors, but when I run a query like this:

```
query {
  listUsers {
    id
    firstName
    lastName
    email
    password
    profile {
      __typename
      ... on StudentProfile {
        studentId
      }
      ... on TeacherProfile {
         salaryGrade
     }
    }
  }
}
```

This returns everything except for profile which just returns `null`. I'm using Sequelize to handle my database work, but my understanding of Unions was that it would simply look up the relevant type for the ID being queried and return the appropriate details in the query.

If I'm mistaken, how can I get this query to work?

edit:

My list user resolver:

```
const listUsers = async (root, { filter }, { models }) => {
  const Op = Sequelize.Op
  return models.User.findAll(
    filter
      ? {
          where: {
            [Op.or]: [
              {
                email: filter,
              },
              {
                firstName: filter,
              },
              {
                lastName: filter,
              },
            ],
          },
        }
      : {},
  )
}
```

User model relations (very simple and has no relation to profiles):

```
User.associate = function(models) {
    User.belongsTo(models.UserType)
    User.belongsTo(models.UserRole)
  }
```

and my generic user resolvers:

```
User: {
    async type(type) {
      return type.getUserType()
    },

    async role(role) {
      return role.getUserRole()
    },
  },
```

Comment: Your `resolveType` method is fine -- the problem likely lies with either the resolver or the model. Please share the code for both.

Comment: Hi @DanielRearden - thanks for the reply (again!) I've added my resolvers and the model code :)

Comment: It's not really clear where `profile` would be coming from if you have no relation to a model for it.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, so in that respect I'd need to add relations to StudentProfile, TeacherProfile etc in my User model?

Comment: Yes, although querying multiple models and then combining the results can be bothersome. You might consider using a single model in front of either a single table or a view that aggregates multiple tables.

Comment: Is there somewhere I can see an example of this in action? I'm having trouble trying to figure out the best way to aggregate multiple tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to go about this is to utilize a single table (i.e. [single table inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Table_Inheritance)).

- Create a table that includes columns for all the types. For example, it would include both `student_id` and `salary_grade` columns, even though these will be exposed as fields on separate types in your schema.
- Add a "type" column that identifies each row's actual type. In practice, it's helpful to name this column `__typename` (more on that later).
- Create a Sequelize model for your table. Again, this model will include all attributes, even if they don't apply to a specific type.
- Define your GraphQL types and your interface/union type. You can provide a `__resolveType` method that returns the appropriate type name based on the "type" field you added. However, if you named this field `__typename` and populated it with the names of the GraphQL types you are exposing, you can actually skip this step!
- You can use your model like normal, utilizing `find` methods to query your table or creating associations with it. For example, you might add a relationship like `User.belongsTo(Profile)` and then lazy load it: `User.findAll({ include: [Profile] })`.

The biggest drawback to this approach is you lose database- and model-level validation. Maybe `salary_grade` should never be null for a `TeacherProfile` but you cannot enforce this with a constraint or set the `allowNull` property for the attribute to `false`. At best, you can only rely on GraphQL's type system to enforce validation but this is not ideal.

You *can* take this a step further and create additional Sequelize models for each individual "type". These models would still point to the same table, but would only include attributes specific to the fields you're exposing for each type. This way, you could at least enforce "required" attributes at the model level. Then, for example, you use your `Profile` model for querying all profiles, but use the `TeacherProfile` when inserting or updating a teacher profile. This works pretty well, just be mindful that you *cannot* use the `sync` method when structuring your models like this -- you'll need to handle migrations manually. You shouldn't use `sync` in production anyway, so it's not a *huge* deal, but definitely something to be mindful of.

Comment: That is extremely helpful, thank you for taking the time!